# Loop through dataframe rows and add value in a new column (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe (df) with a column of Latitude (Lat), and I need to match up the corresponding Longitude value (based off relationships in another dataset). New column name is 'Long_matched'.

Here, I am trying to write a new value in the column 'Long_matched' at the corresponding row to latitudes between -33.9238 and -33.9236. The data in 'Lat' has many more decimal places (e.g: -33.9238026666667,  -33.9236026666667, etc.). As I will be applying this code to multiple datasets over the same geographical location (hence the long decimals will vary slightly), I want to write Longitude values which fall within a a 0.0002 degree range.

Some attempts of code I have tried include:

```
df$Long_matched <- ifelse(df$Lat< -33.9236 & df$Lat> -33.9238, 151.2279 , "N/A")
```

or

```
df$Long_matched[df$Lat< -33.9236 & df$Lat> -33.9238] <- 151.2279
```

I think I need to use a for loop to loop through the rows and an if statement, but struggling to figure this out - any help would be appreciated!

Resulting output should look something like this:

```
Lat                   Long_matched
-33.9238026666667     151.2279
-33.9236026666667     (new long value will go here)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do the comparison between adjacent elements of 'Lat' ?

Comment: Post a few rows of example input. Your code is confusing because your first line modifies `df` and your second line modifies a different data frame named `df_avg`... probably you just need to `merge(df1, df2)`? But very hard to tell without sample inputs and desired output.

Comment: No, I just want to add a new value in the 'Long_matched' column in the row that matches particular 'Lat' values. I already know what the value I want to add is.

Comment: In your description, there are two datasets.  It is confusing

Comment: Sorry Gregor, my mistake! Just edited it - the dataframe is the same :)

Comment: There is no row between -33.9238 and -33.9236.

Comment: Thanks Jfly, I've edited my question to provide some more details. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Can you round Lat to a number to be directly matched?

Comment: If you use `"N/A"` the entire column will be coerced to class `character`.

Answer (score 3):

Everything said in the comments applies, but here is a trick you can try:
In the following code, you will need to replace text with numbers.

```
Latitude_breaks <- seq(min_latitude, max_latitude, 0.0002) # you need to replace `min_latitude`, `max_latitude`, and `increment` with numbers
Longitude_values <- seq(first, last, increment) # you need to replace `first`, `last` and `increment` with numbers
df <- within(df, {
  # make a categorical version of `Lat`
  Lat_cat <- cut(Lat, Latitude_breaks)
  Long_matched <- Longitude_values[Lat_cat]
})
```

A few notes:

1. the values between `min_latitude` and `min_latitude + 1` will be assigned to the values of `Longitude` marked first.
2. The length of `Latitude_beaks` should be one more than the length of `Longitude_values`.
3. Values of `Lat` outside of `Latitude_breaks` will becomes NAs.

This works by exploiting a nice feature of factors - they are stored as integers.  So we can use them to index another vector - in this case, `Longitude_values`.